# Routing particular service over vpn

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

Running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I need to connect to a SMB share that isn't local. The only way I can connect to it is over a VPN. The particular VPN service is Juniper. Connecting to the VPN is easy and already done. It creates a tunnel which shows in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

So, how do I only send SMB traffic to this particular server over the VPN. Is it possible?

Unfortunately I cannot implement any other protocol as that is out of my control.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that, as for your Linux box:

1. the SMB client connection will start from the Linux-box itself (in other words: your linux box is *not* acting as a router for your local LAN traffic);
2. the VPN interface is "*tun0*", with a local IP <*local_VPN_IP*> and a remote P2P IP <*remote_VPN_P2P_IP*>;
3. the remote SMB server to be reached via VPN is <*remote_SMB_SERVER*> (hostname or IP);

probably the better way to route SMB traffic (and only it...) through the VPN is to:

a) using netfilter/iptables to "mangle" outgoing SMB packets with an identifier (eg.: 1);

b) instruct the routing process to route packet "mangled" with id "1" different from other packets, and specifically through the VPN.

Following commands should give you an idea (please note that I'm writing them without strict checking):

```
# Let's MARK outgoing SMB traffic towards remote_SMB_SERVER with id: "1"
iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -d <remote_SMB_SERVER> --dport 137 -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -d <remote_SMB_SERVER> --dport 138 -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -d <remote_SMB_SERVER> --dport 139 -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -d <remote_SMB_SERVER> --dport 445 -j MARK --set-mark 1

# Let's create a routing table to be used for above MARKed packets:
echo 201 smb.out >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip rule add fwmark 1 table smb.out

# Let's add a route entry to properly forward MARKed SMB packets through 
# the smb.out routing table
/sbin/ip route add -host <remote_SMB_SERVER> via <remote_VPN_P2P_IP> dev tun0 table smb.out
```

For any further details, please refer to the very well documented LARTC HOWTO [http://www.lartc.org/howto/lartc.netfilter.html]

As a side note:

- please note that the /etc/network/interfaces file contains configuration data for your network interfaces, and does *NOT* get updated when your VPN connection defines/bring_up a proper interface;
- I wonder why you want to route through the VPN "only" the SMB traffic of remote_SMB_SERVER... and not the rest (eg.: HTTP or SMTP, also towards remote_SMB_SERVER).

(BTW: please be kind with this answer, as it's my second one in the ServerFault/StackExchange arena)